# ScrollIntoView doesn't work properly on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, angular-ui

I was trying to use the scrollIntoView() with smoothscroll.polyfill() but I've tried a couple of times to use this functionality on Microsoft Edge and the text goes on top of screen, but on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome centralize the div. Here is the code below:

**app.component.html:**

```
<button (click)="scroll()">Click</button>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
[...]
<div class="hello">Hello World Test</div>
[...]
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
scroll() {
    document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'})
}
```

Note: I'm using Angular v9.1.0 (Latest).

Thanks for all!

Comment: I assume that you are testing with MS Edge (legacy) browser. As smooth behavior is not supported and you are using third party smoothscroll.polyfill(), I suggest you try to create an issue on their GitHub issues page. Ref: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll/issues If you can use the MS Edge Chromium browser then you can avoid this issue in it. Ref: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge